# Android HTTP Post Files with different file formats

Tags: php, android, http-post

Currently, I could HTTP Post text files and Image files using the following code snippets from http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/android-http-client.html

Android portion:

```
// the file to be posted
String textFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sample.txt";
Log.v(TAG, "textFile: " + textFile);

// the URL where the file will be posted
String postReceiverUrl = "http://yourdomain.com/post_data_receiver.php";
Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

// new HttpClient
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// post header
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

File file = new File(textFile);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

// execute HTTP post request
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

if (resEntity != null) {
    
    String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
    Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);
    
    // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
}
```

PHP portion:

```
<?php
// if text data was posted
if($_POST){
    print_r($_POST);
}

// if a file was posted
else if($_FILES){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file["tmp_name"]);
    print_r($fileContents);
}
?>
```

Using the above code snippets HTTP Post of textfiles and Images could be done without any issue. But if I try to HTTP Post other file formats like encrypted file etc. It fails and the file doesn't get posted to the backend.

Any idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file change the following values:

upload_max_filesize & post_max_size

Change it to a more appropriate values depending on the expected filesize.